# Restrict the usage of method decorators

Tags: typescript, generics, decorator

I have a decorator for methods that I want it to be used only with async methods. This is an example of usage:

```
class A {
  @deco() // This should work.
  public async works() { }
  @deco() // This should fail.
  public fails() { }
}
```

I tried to define the decorator like this:

```
export function deco() {
  return <T extends {[K in keyof T]: () => Promise<any>}, 
          K extends string>
         (target: T, 
          propertyKey: K, 
          descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    // Decorator code here.
  };
}
```

But it doesn't work. It fails in both `works` and `fails` methods because the `K` `[K in keyof T]` and the `K` in `K extends string` and `propertyKey: K` are not the same, thus the `K` is not restricted to be a key of T.

This does not work either:

```
export function deco() {
  return <T extends {[K in keyof T]: () => Promise<any>}, 
          K extends keyof T>
         (target: T, 
          propertyKey: K, 
          descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    // Decorator code here.
  };
}
```

Neither this:

```
export function deco() {
  return <T, 
          K extends keyof T>
         (target: T & {[propertyKey]: () => Promise<any>}, 
          propertyKey: K, 
          descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    // Decorator code here.
  };
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a method decorator, not a property decorator:

```
declare type MethodDecorator = <T>(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>) => TypedPropertyDescriptor<T> | void;
```

A decorator that can be added to any method returning a promise would be :

```
function TypeRestrictedMethodDecorator(
    target: Object, // The prototype of the class
    propertyKey: string, // The name of the method
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(... p:any[]) => Promise<any>>
    ) {
    console.log("TypeRestrictedMethodDecorator called on: ", target, propertyKey, descriptor);
}

class TypeRestrictedMethodDecoratorExample {
    @TypeRestrictedMethodDecorator
    method(num: number): Promise<number> {
        return new Promise((res, rej)=> res(10));
    }

    @TypeRestrictedMethodDecorator // Error
    method2(num: number): number {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Sample modified from [here](https://github.com/arolson101/typescript-decorators)

Comment: What was exactly the problem? Using PropertyDescriptor instead of TypedPropertyDescriptor?

Comment: The `PropertyDecorator` does not offer a way to restrict based on the type of the target, `MethodDecorator` is generic method and the generic type is the type of the target. Generally since you are decorating a method you should use the a `MethodDecorator` as the name suggests